# Problem to get correct bounding box around the mesh and raycasting for gltf model with skinnedmesh

Tags: three.js, raycasting, bounding-box

The idea is to import a gltf model into my scene and enclose all the children object of it inside a single bounding box. In most of the cases, these works without any issue. But in some cases when some of the children are skinnedmesh, bounding box is not covering all the children.

Please try with [Test.glb - Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17gHdFLh4YpNydYXdV6CW17bvoC_O_UMK/view?usp=share_link) so you can understand the issue. Even the issue can be seen in Three.js Editor too.

Also I can not raycast it correctly.

Can you please help me to sort out? I have already read about having manual bounding box or/and frustumCulled=false of skinned mesh and I need to load models dynamically sothat can not manually define the Bounding Box.

```
 loader.load(filename,
    function (gltf) {
     let mgroup = new THREE.Group();
      while (gltf.scene.children.length > 0) {
        var child = gltf.scene.children[0];
        if (child.isObject3D) {
          mgroup.add(child);
        }
      }
      scene.add(mgroup);
      const aabb = new THREE.BoxHelper(mgroup);
      scene.add(aabb);
    });
```

Comment: You must add the code in the question. Links to external resources tend to break or the content may change. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"*

Comment: @Rabbid76 thank you for commenting. As I mentioned in my original post, you can reproduce the issue in Three.js Editor. You just need to import the glb model I have added in my original post. But since you are suggesting so I am adding a code block related to the issue.